# Arrays en javascript en bucle for

Tags: javascript, array

estoy intentando sacar de un array ya creada, los numeros que acaban en 0 y guardarlos en un array nueva y los numeros que no acaben en 0 tambien guardarla en un array nueva. Despues con dos alerts sacar las arrays nuevas por separado y que te muestre cuantos elementos hay en esa array y ademas la suma total de los elementos que tenga.

Tengo esto pero me da error cuando me saca los alert finales:

```js
let arrlistaNumero = [];
do {
  let i = +prompt("Introduce números positivo, si desea salir, introduzca un número negativo");
  if (i >= 0){
    arrlistaNumero.push(i);
  } else {
      break;
  }
} while (true);
alert(`el listado tiene ${arrlistaNumero.length} numeros: ${arrlistaNumero}`)

let arrnumAcabaNoCero = [];
let arrnumAcabaCero = []
let suma=0;

for(i=0; i <= arrlistaNumero.length; i++){
    if (i / 10 != 0){
        arrnumAcabaNoCero.push(i);
        suma += arrnumAcabaNoCero[i];
    } else {
        arrnumAcabaCero.push(i);
        suma += arrnumAcabaCero[i]; 
    }
}
alert(arrnumAcabaNoCero + suma)
alert(arrnumAcabaCero + suma)
```

Answer (score 0):

Tienes varios errores. Empecemos:

1. En el bucle for te estas saliendo del array al poner menor o igual. Piensa que los arrays empiezan en posición 0. Si su longitud es de 5, su última "celda" es la número 4
2. Dentro del for no haces referecia nunca a los numeros de tu lista arrlistaNumero porque usas i que es el entero que recorre tu lista. Debes usar arrlistaNumero[i].
3. La condición que aplicas en el if para saber si acaba por cero es errónea. 50 acaba en 0 y 50 / 10 no cumple tu condición pues vale 5 que es != 0. en su lugar debes evaluar el resto de la división.

El for quedaría tal que así

```
for(let i=0; i < arrlistaNumero.length; i++){
    let actualNumero = arrlistaNumero[i]
    if (actualNumero % 10 != 0){
        arrnumAcabaNoCero.push(actualNumero);
        suma += arrnumAcabaNoCero[i];
    } else {
        arrnumAcabaCero.push(actualNumero);
        suma += arrnumAcabaCero[i];
    }
}
```

Esto te va a seguir dando error en la suma pero las listas estarán correctas, no devolvías los números. Te dara Nan por el siguiente motivo: imaginate que introducimos los valores 20, 30, 5. Las dos primeras veces entraremos en el else añadiremos esos dos numeros y la suma valdrá 50. Ahora entramos con el 5 (con lo que la i será igual a 2), que no termina en cero y entraremos en el if y aquí vendra el probema:

```
suma += arrnumAcabaNoCero[i];
```

El valor de i = 2 y arrnumAcabaNoCero esta totalmente vacía asi que eso se evaluará a undefined. Así que hara 50 + undefined = NaN.

La solución es hacer la suma fuera de ese for ya que las listas pueden o no tener la misma longitud y sabes en que orden te vienen los numeros. Solo funcionará si todos los numeros termian en cero o ninguno. Así que, después de ese for calculas la suma. Deberás de recorrer cada lista con un for y ir acumulando en la variable suma. Aunque por lo que veo quieres obtener una suma general de tu lista original. Podrías tu lista inicial y vas sumando y listo, incluso conforme añades los números con el prompt ya los puedes ir sumando!

Para sumar todos los elementos de una lista puedes usar la funcion de reduce que ofrece js:

```
suma = arrnumAcabaNoCero.reduce((acc, index) => acc + index)
```